# How to turn off text suggestion for TextFieldTTF cocos2dx?

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-x

I am using TextFieldTTF in cocos2dx 3.6 for some reason I cannot use EditBox, I want to turn off text suggestion appeared above keyboard but there is no method to disable these text suggestion in TextFieldTTF. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

May I ask you about why you can't use EditBox? (its because of alignment issues ?)

For TextFieldTTF you can try to call `setSecureTextEntry (bool value)`.

It might off text suggestion, but you will faced with new problem - text can be shown as *****. This problem you may try to resolve by implement IMEDelegate.